# Run a shell function in the background (using &) but still retrieve results

Tags: bash

Is it possible to call a BASH function with '&' and return a value? Or is there a better way? Basically I want to run the same command several times in parallel and capture the data.

In this sample pointless code, I would like to get the value from the function but it is not assigned. If I can do this then I can call a function and pass it values in parallel.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

return_var=''

function pass_back_a_string() {
    eval "$1='foo bar rab oof'"
    sleep 2
}

pass_back_a_string return_var &
wait
echo $return_var
```

Comment: Not with `eval` or any equivalent to it, no -- spawns a subshell running in a completely separate process, has no access to the parent's memory.

Comment: ...in general, you'll want to have your spawned-off processes write to a file, a named pipe, create contents in a directory with the filename keyed to the individual process, or otherwise something like that. Deciding which of those approaches is a better fit depends on details you haven't provided.

Comment: If you run it multiple times in parallel, which one's value would you expect to capture?

Comment: @Barmar, since the destination variable name is an explicit argument, I think it's pretty clear that the intent is to have each instance write to a different destination.

Comment: ...btw -- in general, `eval "$1=..."` is risky if you aren't being careful about it. `eval "$1=$2"` will do Very Bad Things if `$2` contains, say, `$(rm -rf ~)`. If its text comes from a filename, or content retrieved from a database, are you sure that those values are *always* guaranteed to be safe? Now, `eval "$1="'$2'` is a different matter, and much safer: Because the `$2` is quoted such that its value is expanded *after* `eval` is invoked, its contents don't go through the parsing stages with the most security exposure... but that goes to my point that it's necessary to be cautious.

Comment: ...anyhow, there are much safer ways to set a variable with an unknown name; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with bash 4.x and coprocesses:

```
#!/bin/bash
# REQUIRES BASH 4.1+

pbas() {
  sleep 10
  printf '%s\0' "hello, world: $RANDOM"
}

echo "Starting coprocesses $SECONDS seconds after interpreter startup"

# Start three coprocesses
coproc cp1 { pbas; }
coproc cp2 { pbas; }
coproc cp3 { pbas; }

# Read results from each in turn
IFS= read -r -d '' result1 <&${cp1[0]}
IFS= read -r -d '' result2 <&${cp2[0]}
IFS= read -r -d '' result3 <&${cp3[0]}

# Emit said results
echo "Result 1: $result1"
echo "Result 2: $result2"
echo "Result 3: $result3"

echo "Exiting $SECONDS seconds after interpreter startup"
```

You'll observe that it correctly exits roughly 10 seconds after interpreter startup, as opposed to the 30 you would get if each instance of the function ran in the parent shell.

---

Now, if you want to get a bit trickier (and, for this example, rely on bash 4.3), you can do even more interesting things -- reducing the amount of repetitive code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# REQUIRES BASH 4.3+

pbas() {
  sleep 10
  printf '%s\0' "hello, world: $RANDOM"
}

declare -A all_coprocs=( )
start_coproc() {
  local retval_name=$1; shift
  local eval_header eval_str eval_footer
  printf -v eval_header 'coproc cp_%q { ' "$retval_name"
  printf -v eval_str '%q ' "$@"
  printf -v eval_footer '; }'
  eval "${eval_header}${eval_str}${eval_footer}"
  all_coprocs[$retval_name]="cp_${retval_name}"
}

collect_results() {
  local retval_name
  for retval_name in "${!all_coprocs[@]}"; do
    declare -n cp=${all_coprocs[$retval_name]}
    IFS= read -r -d '' "$retval_name" <&${cp[0]}
    unset -n cp
  done
}

start_coproc result1 pbas
start_coproc result2 pbas
start_coproc result3 pbas
collect_results

echo "Result 1: $result1"
echo "Result 2: $result2"
echo "Result 3: $result3"

echo "Exiting $SECONDS seconds after interpreter startup"
```

---

Now, if you only have bash 3.x, then things get trickier: You don't have automatic FD allocation, or coprocesses, or support for redirecting from file descriptors named by variables [except by using `eval`]. However, you can generate named pipes; spawn off subprocesses that write to them; and then read from them in the collection phase.

```
#!/bin/bash
# REQUIRES BASH 3.2+

declare -a destvars=( )
declare -a destdirs=( )
declare -a destfds=( )
nextfd=10

pbas() { sleep 10; printf '%s\0' "hello, world: $RANDOM"; }

start_proc() {
  local destvar=$1; shift
  local destdir=$(mktemp -d "${TEMPDIR:-/tmp}/coproc-emulation.XXXXXX")
  local idx=$(( ${#destdirs[@]} + 1 ))
  local eval_str
  mkfifo "$destdir/outpipe"
  ( "$@" ) >"$destdir/outpipe" & procs[$idx]=$!
  printf -v eval_str 'exec %q<%q' "$nextfd" "$destdir/outpipe"
  eval "$eval_str"
  destdirs[$idx]=$destdir
  destvars[$idx]=$destvar
  destfds[$idx]=$((nextfd++))
}

collect_results() {
  local idx destdir destvar destfd
  for idx in "${!destvars[@]}"; do
    destvar=${destvars[$idx]}
    destdir=${destdirs[$idx]}
    destfd=${destfds[$idx]}
    printf -v eval_str 'IFS= read -r -d "" %q <&%q' "$destvar" "$destfd"
    eval "$eval_str"
    rm -rf "$destdir"
    unset destvars[$idx] destdirs[$idx] destfds[$idx]
  done
}

start_proc result1 pbas
start_proc result2 pbas
start_proc result3 pbas

collect_results

echo "Result 1: $result1"
echo "Result 2: $result2"
echo "Result 3: $result3"

echo "Exiting $SECONDS seconds after interpreter startup"
```

Comment: Thank you!  It should be noted that you can run a command and echo it back or write it to a file.  In the past I would spawn a bunch of threads and let them echo to the screen what they did (nmap on a system). Or I will have them perform work and just quit, no contact needed. etc..